# Android SMS Manager

Tags: java, android, sms

I've been thinking about working on an app that allows a user to send text messages for free to other users of the application. I thought I would use the SMS Manager API to accomplish this.

My question is, does the SMS Manager API send an sms using the phone's texting plan ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

All "SMS" is carried out by the carrier. If you would like app to app messaging, you need data. Either through a carrier or Wi-Fi.